# Julia: Questions about array where the dimension is not determined

Tags: arrays, julia

I have two beginner's questions:

(1) I want to reshape an array, but dimensions come from a vector which can be a variable. For example,

```
A = ones(120,1)
b = [2,3,4,5]
```

I can write

```
C = reshape(A,2,3,4,5)
```

But in case b can vary, I want something like

```
C = reshape(A,b)
```

This code works in Matlab. Is there an analog in Julia?

(2) I want to slice a high-dimensional array, while keeping the dimensions flexible. In the example above, I fix the last dimension:

```
C[:,:,:,1]
C[:,:,:,2]
```

etc. The problem is to find an efficient way: For an array of any dimensions, I can always fix the last dimension and extract values.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) `C = reshape(A,b...)`

(2) [EllipsisNotation.jl](https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/EllipsisNotation.jl) provides a `..` operator, so `C[..,1]` does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

And there is `C[ntuple(x->:, ndims(C)-1)..., 1]` for (2) if you don't want to install a package.